# vue transition, not rolling as intended without mode="out-in"

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, css-transitions, vue-component

So I'm having trouble understanding why without `mode="out-in"` the transition doesn't roll from the top down to the bottom.

With the `out-in` it rolls as intended (though with the delay), but without the `out-in` it rolls down, then just pops into existence.

Here's my codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/2zlr154m1r

Vue files for future reference:

App.vue

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <button @click="toggleExamples">switched</button>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <transition name="rolling-down">
        <component :is="which" />
      </transition>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <transition name="rolling-down" mode="out-in">
        <component :is="other" />
      </transition>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import HelloWorld from "./components/HelloWorld";
import Example1 from "./components/Example1";
import Example2 from "./components/Example2";

export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {
    "example-one": Example1,
    "example-two": Example2,
    HelloWorld
  },
  data() {
    return {
      which: "example-one",
      other: "example-two"
    };
  },
  methods: {
    toggleExamples() {
      let array = ["example-one", "example-two"];
      this.which = array[+(this.which === "example-one")];
      this.other = array[+(this.other === "example-one")];
    }
  }
};
</script>

<style>
#app {
  font-family: "Avenir", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-align: center;
  color: #2c3e50;
  margin-top: 60px;
}
.rolling-down-enter-active,
.rolling-down-leave-active {
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
.rolling-down-enter {
  transform: translateY(-100%);
}
.rolling-down-enter-to {
  transform: translateY(0);
}
.rolling-down-leave {
  transform: translateY(0);
}
.rolling-down-leave-to {
  transform: translateY(100%);
}

.wrapper {
  border: 2px solid black;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 30vh;
}
</style>
```

Example1.vue

```
<template>
  <div class="parent">
    example1
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {};
</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped>
.parent {
  height: 30vh;
  width: 100vw;
  background-color: red;
}
</style>
```

Example2.vue

```
<template>
  <div class="parent">
    this is example2
    asfads
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {};
</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped>
.parent {
  height: 30vh;
  width: 100vw;
  background-color: blue;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realised what it was. It's because the element is actually appearing alongside the leaving element, but because of its positioning, it appears underneath.

https://codesandbox.io/s/ykqq6oov6j

To solve it, you need to apply `position: absolute` to the transitioning components